# Get elements just 1 level below the current element by javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to access the DOM tree and get the elements just 1 level below the current element.

Read the following code:

```
<div id="node">
    <div id="a">
        <div id="aa">
            <div id="ab">
                <div id="aba"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <div id="ba">
            <div id="bb">
                <div id="bba"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        <div id="ca">
            <div id="cb">
                <div id="cba"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the 3 elements "a", "b", "c" under "node". What should I do?

var nodes = node.getElementsByTagName("div") <---- I get all the divs but not the 3 divs I need.

var nodes = node.childNodes; <---- works in IE, but FF contains Text Node

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a function that rules out all non-element nodes:

```
function getChildNodes(node) {
    var children = new Array();
    for(var child in node.childNodes) {
        if(node.childNodes[child].nodeType == 1) {
            children.push(child);
        }
    }
    return children;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me out - tip for other users - it's children.push(child);

Comment: You might also consider splice() to delete nodes. It might be a little bit faster?

Answer (score 4):

Try this (late answer, but can be useful for others):

```
var list;
list=document.getElementById("node").querySelectorAll("#node>div");
```

Answer (score 4):

[Universal selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) can do the trick:

```
var subNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#node > *");
```

Query parts:

`#node` is unique container selector

`>` next slector should be applied only on childs

`*` universal selector that match every tag but not text

[Can I use universal selector](https://caniuse.com/#search=universal%20selector)

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend you look at [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com).  The task you're looking to do is straightforward in pure Javascript, but if you're doing any additional DOM traversal, JQuery is going to save you countless hours of frustration.  Not only that but it works across all browsers and has a very good "document ready" method.

Your problem solved with JQuery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var children = $("#node").children();
});
```

It looks for any element with an id of "node" then returns its children.  In this case, `children` is a JQuery collection that can be iterated over using a for loop.  Additionally you could iterate over them using the each() command.

Answer (score 2):

This is simplier than you think:

```
var nodes = node.querySelector("node > div");
```

Comment: That won't work if the node contains an other node of the same type.

Comment: `..querySelectorAll` ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way to do this is to add a class name to the
    first level child nodes:

```
<div id="node">
    <div id="a" class="level_1">
        <div id="aa">
            <div id="ab">
                <div id="aba"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="level_1">
        <div id="ba">
            <div id="bb">
                <div id="bba"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c" class="level_1">
        <div id="ca">
            <div id="cb">
                <div id="cba"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then to use the method `getElementsByClassName`, so in this case:

```
document.getElementById('node').getElementsByClassName('level_1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think node.childNodes is the right place to start. You could (to make it work with FF too), test the nodeName (and possibly nodeType) of all child nodes you get, to skip text nodes.

Also you might have a look at some javascript library like [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), which provide a lot of useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some text so we can see that it is working, and JavaScript that will add "added!" to the bottom of each of the divs at the base:

```js
var cDiv = document.querySelectorAll('body > div > div'), i;
for (i = 0; i < cDiv.length; i++)
{
 cDiv[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode('added!'));
}
```

```html
<div id="node">
    <div id="a">a
        <div id="aa">aa
            <div id="ab">ab
                <div id="aba">aba</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b">b
        <div id="ba">ba
            <div id="bb">bb
                <div id="bba">bba</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c">c
        <div id="ca">ca
            <div id="cb">cb
                <div id="cba">cba</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```